# PC restarts because HDD issues

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

There is an old PC which keeps restarting after the Windows 7 loading screen.

What I tried:

- Startup Repair with the original installation CD (from USB)
- System Restore. It says there are no changes onto the file system

It however couldn't find the problem.

After a few restarts, it displayed a message "A disk read error occurred", which means the HDD has bad sectors.

There used to be one more PC just like this one with the same issue and when I attached its HDD to HD Sentinel, the response was 37% HDD health.

Is there a way to make it run even with the bad sectors? This PC is used only for Internet browsing.

Answer (score 0):

```
chkdsk /R c:
```

First you will have to say YES to do it after a reboot.  Then you will have to reboot so it can scan your hard drive.  It WILL take a long time to run, but it will mark all the current bad sectors so windows doesn't try to use them.

However, if your drive is that bad it may grown NEW bad sectors, and you may have to re-run chkdsk daily as the drive nears its failing point.

**You DO have a backup don't you?**
Your drive is probably going to die soon and take ALL your data with it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I did that through the installation CD's command prompt. However, the result was "Windows has checked the file system and found no problems.". It says 0 KB in bad sectors and "Failed to transfer logged messages to the event log with status 50. https://i.imgur.com/35kIFtk.jpeg

Comment: Perhaps, there should be a way to check logs? If everything is okay as it says, why it still keeps restarting?

Comment: May it be RAM issues?

Comment: @nop You checked the wrong drive letter, the one you checked is 100mb.  When you boot from a CD the drive letters are different.  Please find the correct drive letter and try again.  If you have the correct drive it should take hours to complete.

Comment: In fact you were right. It was actually E:, C: was the System Reserved partition. I waited it a few hours, but Windows 7 still restarts itself.

Comment: @nop Did it report finding any bad sectors?  Are you still getting "A disk read error occurred"?

Comment: it reported that it moved something in order to prevent these bad sectors from popping up or something like that, but I don't know. It still doesn't work. I forgot to take a screenshot, maybe I should redo it and take a screenshot?